# What does it mean when a node is activated in dynatree?

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

From this source http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html

> node.activate()
>
> Activate this node - according to flag - and fire a
> onActivate event. If activeVisible option is set, all parents will be
> expanded as necessary. Focus is not set.

What does it mean when a node is activated? It's not very intuitive. I understand expand and collapse as well as if a node is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of Fancytree (the successor of Dynatree):
https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/FAQ#q-what-statuses-can-a-node-have

A node may be active, selected, focused, and/or hovered.
These states are independent, so one node can have all, some, or none of these 
states at the same time:

- hovered
  Only one (or no) node can be hovered at any given time.
  A node becomes hovered, when the mouse pointer rests over it.
- focused
  Only one (or no) node can be focused at any given time.
  A node becomes focused, when the user presses TAB to enter the tree, or
  by pressing UP / DOWN keys.
  Note: if the `autoActivate` option is set, a node will be automatically 
  activated, when it receives focus. (Use Ctrl-UP / Ctrl-DOWN keys to 
  focus only.)
- active
  Only one (or no) node can be active at any given time.
  A node becomes active by a mouse click, keyboard navigation, or pressing 
  SPACE on a focused node (or using UP, DOWN, when the `autoActivate` option 
  is set).
  A typical use case would be to use the tree for navigation, 
  i.e. to display details of the *active* node in a separate pane.
- selected
  None, one, or multiple nodes can be selected at any given time.
  If the `checkbox` option is active, this will also reflect the select-state.
  However in selectMode 1 ('single selection'), only one node is selectable, so the behavior is
  comparable to radio-buttons.
  A use case would be to allow the user to *select* several elements out 
  of a set of hierarchical elements.

(Other statuses include 'expanded', 'lazy', 'disabled', ...)

Comment: Thanks! That use case was what I was looking for.